# How to open new tab in the current gnome-terminal window?

Tags: zsh, gnome-terminal

I ran `gnome-terminal --working-directory=$DIR` but it opens in a new window, not tab.

Things I've tried:

```
--tab
-T
--add-tab
```

Running RHEL5 with zsh

Comment: You cannot, you have to use something like xdotool to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line

Answer (score 2):

Verbatim copy of the only way to do this that I've ever seen, using `xdotool`, `xprop`, & `wmctrl`.

*Source: [Open a new tab in gnome-terminal using command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1188959/open-a-new-tab-in-gnome-terminal-using-command-line)*

```
#!/bin/sh

WID=$(xprop -root | grep "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)"| awk '{print $5}')
xdotool windowfocus $WID
xdotool key ctrl+shift+t
wmctrl -i -a $WID
```

This will auto determine the corresponding terminal and opens the tab accordingly.

Comment: What about using `xdotool key ctrl+shift+t` only?

Comment: @Pandya - you need to get the window's ID so that you can force xdotool to focus on it prior. Without these there are various situations where the above won't work otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to open a new tab into an alredy-existing gnome-terminal window try ctrl-shift-t

Comment: I know that option, but I am intentionally asking for shell scripting